# Show custom text block on product page only if a product is out of stock with backorder enabled

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

i have a wordpress site with woocommerce and flatsome theme. The theme give the possibility to add easily a custom html text before or after the add to cart button.

I would like that the html text show up only for out of stock with backorder enabled products, for single and variables products.

the theme have this code

```
  // Add HTML after Add to Cart button
function flatsome_after_add_to_cart_html(){
    echo do_shortcode(get_theme_mod('html_after_add_to_cart'));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'flatsome_after_add_to_cart_html', 30);
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please check the Stackoverflow guide on how to ask questions -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can likely do that with just an additional couple of checks in your function. Before echoing the content - check the $product like this:

```
function flatsome_after_add_to_cart_html(){
    global $product;
    if( ! $product->is_in_stock() && $product->backorders_allowed() ){
        echo do_shortcode(get_theme_mod('html_after_add_to_cart'));
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'flatsome_after_add_to_cart_html', 30);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code, i don't why but unfortunately doesn't work, the text box disappear for all products status.

Comment: Hi @JBoss,  removed the exclamation mark before $products and now working good for simple products. I have only the problem on variable product, works good when all variations are out of stock, but when 1 or more variation are in stock the html text is visible. There is a way to show up only when i select an out of stock variation product? Really thanks for all for putting me on the right path!